# Why were not all petitionary prayers eliminated on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, shemoneh-esrei, kaddish

Jewish teaching is that Shabbat services are for thanks and praise, not for petition [see Berachot Yerushalmi].  That's why the rabbis cut out the middle 13 blessings of the daily Amidah.

But we still petition God on Shabbat:  Hashkivenu, Oseh shalom, Mi shebberach, prayers for the government and for Israel, etc.  So why did we not go all the way?  What is the dividing line?

[Sephardim cut out the middle part of Hashkivenu (Vehagen baadenu...), but curiously leave the rest (ufros alenu...)]

Comment: Almost all your examples are not original

Comment: @DoubleAA -- Thanks for the references.  But "original" relative to what?

Comment: To time? The prayer service removed nearly all petitions. Then later in time various people (often but not always kabbalists) decided to add in various petitions due to their "extreme importance"